# fusion de 3 select

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT  vendedores.Nombre,SUM(factura.Total) FROM vendedores,factura 
WHERE 
vendedores.Codigo=factura.CodigoVendedor 
AND factura.Fecha BETWEEN '2018-09-13' AND '2018-09-14' GROUP BY 
vendedores.Nombre


SELECT  vendedores.Nombre,SUM(sales.Total) FROM vendedores,sales WHERE 
vendedores.Codigo=sales.CodigoVendedor 
AND sales.Fecha BETWEEN '2018-09-13' AND '2018-09-14' GROUP BY 
vendedores.Nombre



SELECT vendedores.Nombre,SUM(abonos.Abono) AS Total FROM 
vendedores,abonos,saldos WHERE abonos.NumFactura=saldos.NumFactura AND 
saldos.CodigoVendedor=vendedores.Codigo AND abonos.Fecha BETWEEN '2018- 
09-13' AND '2018-09-14' GROUP BY vendedores.Nombre
```

Como hago para que esos 3 sum() de esas 3 consultas sean uno solo? Es decir poder obtener el resultado de esas 3 sumatorias.

Answer (score 2):

Intenta con este select:

```
Selecr sum (*) from (
SELECT  SUM(factura.Total) valor FROM vendedores,factura 
WHERE 
vendedores.Codigo=factura.CodigoVendedor 
AND factura.Fecha BETWEEN '2018-09-13' AND '2018-09-14' GROUP BY 
vendedores.Nombre
Union
SELECT  SUM(sales.Total) valor2 FROM vendedores,sales WHERE 
vendedores.Codigo=sales.CodigoVendedor 
AND sales.Fecha BETWEEN '2018-09-13' AND '2018-09-14' GROUP BY 
vendedores.Nombre
Union
SELECT SUM(abonos.Abono) valor3 FROM 
vendedores,abonos,saldos WHERE abonos.NumFactura=saldos.NumFactura AND 
saldos.CodigoVendedor=vendedores.Codigo AND abonos.Fecha BETWEEN '2018- 
09-13' AND '2018-09-14' GROUP BY vendedores)a
```

Answer (score 1):

@Alfredo Paz mil gracias ya habia encontrado la respuesta ysi es muy parecida a la suya, yo creo que igual: 
SELECT v.Nombre,(SELECT SUM(factura.Total) FROM factura WHERE v.Codigo=factura.CodigoVendedor AND factura.Tipo='Factura' AND factura.Fecha BETWEEN '2018-09-13' AND '2018-09-14' GROUP BY v.Nombre)+(SELECT SUM(sales.Total) FROM sales WHERE v.Codigo=sales.CodigoVendedor AND sales.Fecha BETWEEN '2018-09-13' AND '2018-09-14' GROUP BY v.Nombre)+(SELECT SUM(abonos.Abono) FROM abonos,saldos WHERE abonos.NumFactura=saldos.NumFactura AND saldos.CodigoVendedor=v.Codigo AND abonos.Fecha BETWEEN '2018-09-13' AND '2018-09-14' GROUP BY v.Nombre) as Total FROM vendedores AS v

Comment: la respuesta no es mia Richard, si no de @Yeiro entonces considera calificarsela si te sirvió dándole un +1

Answer (score 0):

```
Select sum (*) from (
SELECT  SUM(factura.Total) valor FROM vendedores,factura 
WHERE 
vendedores.Codigo=factura.CodigoVendedor 
AND factura.Fecha BETWEEN '2018-09-13' AND '2018-09-14' GROUP BY 
vendedores.Nombre
IN
`SELECT`  SUM(sales.Total) valor2 FROM vendedores,sales WHERE 
vendedores.Codigo=sales.CodigoVendedor 
AND sales.Fecha BETWEEN '2018-09-13' AND '2018-09-14' GROUP BY 
vendedores.Nombre
IN
`SELECT` SUM(abonos.Abono) valor3 FROM 
vendedores,abonos,saldos WHERE abonos.NumFactura=saldos.NumFactura AND 
saldos.CodigoVendedor=vendedores.Codigo AND abonos.Fecha BETWEEN '2018- 
09-13' AND '2018-09-14' GROUP BY vendedores)a
```

Comment: Por favor agrega una descripción clara de qué hace este código. Mira aquí [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.